# nginx url rewrite getting failed

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to migrate my .htaccess rules to nginx. I have tried almost all the questions on SO &  [url rewriter](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) as well but not getting success. In short i want to convert following dynamic urls:

from

```
[1] - https://vc.test/results.php?url=ngo-service
[2] - https://vc.test/jobs.php?d=17&t=oil-&-gas
[3] - https://vc.test/jobs.php?d=17
```

To

```
[1] - https://vc.test/ngo-service
[2] - https://vc.test/17/oil-&-gas
[3] - https://vc.test/17
```

Request help to sort out this issue.

**My nginx effort**

```
server {
    listen      127.0.0.1:80;
    listen      127.0.0.1:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate_key "d:/winnmp/conf/opensslCA/selfsigned/vc.test+4-key.pem";
    ssl_certificate "d:/winnmp/conf/opensslCA/selfsigned/vc.test+4.pem";    
    server_name     vc.test;
    root    "d:/winnmp/www/vc";
        
    ## Access Restrictions
    allow       127.0.0.1;
    deny        all;
        
    autoindex on;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;

        if ($query_string ~* "fbclid="){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1? redirect;
            break;
        }
        
        if ($query_string ~* "url="){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /%1? redirect;
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /results.php?url=$1 permanent;
            break;
        }

        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/(.*)?$ jobs.php?d=$1&t=$2 break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)?$ jobs.php?d=$1 break;

    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include     nginx.fastcgi.conf;
        include     nginx.redis.conf;
        fastcgi_pass    php_farm;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith, your suggestion solved url issues for [2] & [3]. any idea for [1] url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your `if ($query_string` blocks are for, so I will ignore them.

Use `rewrite...last` if the rewritten URI is to be processed in a different `location` block, for example with URIs ending with `.php`. All Nginx URIs begin with a leading `/`, for example, use `/jobs.php` and not `jobs.php`.

You can place your list of `rewrite` statements in the `location /` block, and they will be evaluated in order until a match is found. If no match is found, the `try_files` statement will be evaluated. *That's just how the rewrite module works!!*

However, the 1st rewrite rule is too general and may break some of the URIs intended to be fulfilled by the `try_files` statement. A better solution may be to put all of the `rewrite` statements into the same named `location` block.

For example:

```
index index.html index.htm index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    if (-f $document_root$uri.php) {
        rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
    }
    rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /jobs.php?d=$1&t=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9]+)$ /jobs.php?d=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)$ /results.php?url=$1 last;
    return 404;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith. Correctly as your assumption, try_files is not not automatically redirecting {https://vc.test/results.php?url=ngo-service} to {https://vc.test/ngo-service}  but above help made this url accessible in both ways. With some changes, i can get this working by my own. Thank you once again for your kind help :-)